# How to Set Width of sap.m.MessagePopover?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

The control [sap.m.MessagePopover](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.MessagePopover/) has an attribute `_oPopover` (containing sap.m.Popover inside).
Using this attribute, I could set the popover width:

```
messagePopover._oPopover.setContentWidth("450px");
```

However, as SAP attributes starting from `_` should not be used, does anybody know a cleaner way?

Comment: Have you tried using `sap.m.MessageView` as suggested in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48987388/5846045) below?

Answer (score 1):

As of UI5 version 1.46, a more flexible control [**`sap.m.MessageView`**](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.MessageView) can be used instead of the old `sap.m.MessagePopover`.

- There is no need to access internal properties or apply custom CSS style classes to manipulate the width as [you can put MessageView anywhere you want](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.MessageView) (Still, Fiori Guideline [recommends](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/message-view/) to use it only [within a responsive popover](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.MessageViewInsideResponsivePopover/preview) or a dialog).

  ```js
  const popover = new ResponsivePopover({
    contentWidth: "450px",
    contentHeight: "450px",
    content: [
      /*myMessageView*/
    ],
  });
  // ...
  popover.openBy(...);
  ```
- Compared to MessagePopover, MessageView can group items and more.
- Internally, [MessagePopover uses MessageView](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/a169e009e17773ee8e933d8b477ad757122d3546) too.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use CSS class. However, there is a catch. As you can see from below generated DOM of the message popover, inline styling has been used :( .
[image]

Only way to override inline-style is by using !important in CSS which is again not recommended approach. However, considering inline CSS has been used, I would go with using !important keyword. Below is the working code:

XML Code ( for adding Class):

```
<MessagePopover id='myMP' class='myPopoverClass'>
    <items>
        <MessagePopoverItem title='Title' subTitle='SubTitle'></MessagePopoverItem>
    </items>
</MessagePopover>
```

CSS:

```
        .myPopoverClass {
            width:100rem;
        }
        .myPopoverClass .sapMPopoverCont {
            width:100% !important;
        }
```

You can play around with how much width you need for message Popover.

EDIT: This is from the source code:

```
MessagePopover.prototype.init = function () {
            var that = this;
            var oPopupControl;

            this._oResourceBundle = sap.ui.getCore().getLibraryResourceBundle("sap.m");

            this._oPopover = new ResponsivePopover(this.getId() + "-messagePopover", {
                showHeader: false,
                contentWidth: "440px",
                placement: this.getPlacement(),
                showCloseButton: false,
                modal: false,
                afterOpen: function (oEvent) {
                    that.fireAfterOpen({openBy: oEvent.getParameter("openBy")});
                },
                afterClose: function (oEvent) {
                    that._navContainer.backToTop();
                    that.fireAfterClose({openBy: oEvent.getParameter("openBy")});
                },
                beforeOpen: function (oEvent) {
                    that.fireBeforeOpen({openBy: oEvent.getParameter("openBy")});
                },
                beforeClose: function (oEvent) {
                    that.fireBeforeClose({openBy: oEvent.getParameter("openBy")});
                }
            }).addStyleClass(CSS_CLASS);
```